# scalaz's disjuntion gives error if type annotation is given in for comprehensin

Tags: scala, scalaz, for-comprehension

Scalaz wants a Monoid instance if I give a type annotation for `v1_b` in the for comprehension below.

1) Why is that ?

2) The error also mentions `filter` , how does `filter` come into this picture ?

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

case class MyError(s:String)

type Err=MyError
val v1: \/[Err, String] = "cool".right
val v2: \/[Err, String] = MyError("not cool").left[String]

val res: \/[Err, (String,String)] =for {
  v1_a <- v1 // this works fine

  // v1_b : String <- v1
  // uncommenting the line above gives the following compiler error:
  // Error:(23, 22) could not find implicit value for parameter M: scalaz.Monoid[_experiment.scalaz.Disjunction.Err]
  // Error:(23, 22) not enough arguments for method filter: (implicit M: scalaz.Monoid[_experiment.scalaz.Disjunction.Err])scalaz.\/[_experiment.scalaz.Disjunction.Err,String].
  // Unspecified value parameter M.

  v2_ <- v2
} yield (v1_a,v2_)

println(res)
```

Try this code online in this fiddle : https://scalafiddle.io/sf/DHO6xki/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v1_b : String` performs a type test at runtime. Therefore, the desugaring of this `for` comprehension has `filter` in it (to filter out cases when the test fails). [`filter` on `\/`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/c7350c08d356dcc0d7157d31eea232e117a577ef/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala#L146) requires the left side to be a monoid.